# Time Interval of 5 miutes in android analog timepickerdialog

Tags: android

I have an android Timepickerdialog which is analog like this:
[image]
I want to customize the minutes which is getting displayed on the the screen left of AM/PM i want to give time interval of 5 minutes if my time is between 0-5 the upper minutes should display 5 , if my time is between 5-10 the minutes should be displayed 10,if its between 10-15 it should display 15 .
basically i dont want minutes such as 1,2,3,4-6,7,8,9-11,12,13,14..... to be displayed when i change time. can anyone help ?
i dont want to change the style of timepickerdialog i want to stick to this same analog one

Here is the code:
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

```
    int modulo = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) % 5;
    if(modulo > 0) {

        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -modulo);
    }

    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);


    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){


        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(android.widget.TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {




        }
    },calendar.HOUR,calendar.MINUTE,false);
    timePickerDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .and try rounding of the time you got from the clock

```
  Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    int modulo = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) % 5;
    if(modulo > 0) {

        calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -modulo);
    }

    myObject.setStartDate(calendar.getTime());

    calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
    myObject.setDueDate(calendar.getTime());
```

Comment: can you explain bit more ?

Comment: try to set the calender before calling your picker and pass this modified calender object to your picker

Comment: you can do one more thing. in onTimeSet  you will get the time ,there you apply the logic which written in answer and convert the time  and set it ..so if you are getting 10.18 then it will show as 10.20 .. i think that what you needed.

Comment: I TRIED TO SET THE TIME in on time set but it isn't working